# Only JDBC Generic driver option in driver template in sts, want SQL Server driver option also

Tags: jdbc, driver, sts

Trying to achieve  JDBC connection to reverse engineer from tables to hibernate using JBOSS tools, need JDBC connection for it, but the option for window->preference->Data Management-> Connectivity->Driver definitions shows only "Generic JDBC Driver" only for connection. Need SQL Server driver option.

[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4HW0.png)

Comment: Why do you need a specific SQL Server option? Why can't you just use the Generic JDBC Driver option, configure it with the SQL Server JDBC driver and connection string? In any case, this could be a matter of having the right plugins (maybe there is an Eclipse Data Tools Platform plugin specifically for SQL Server).

Comment: Tried using the Generic JDBC Driver option but it was giving nullPointerException, I thought may be the driver is reason.